# giving wrong result in when using like ./double square 8

Tags: c, debugging, output

I am writing program to perform some chain operations but it giving wrong result when i run like program is named as double.c

```
./double square 2
output : 4
```

but when i run like

```
./double square 8
output:0
expected output:256
```

I have used fork and someother which were requirement of my program to must use them Please can you spot any logical error Please

I am trying to perform chain operations like `./double square square .... 8`
but it is not working as i want.
**What i have tried is **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define EPSILON 0.001

double simple_abs(double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x : -x;
}

double simple_sqrt(double x)
{
    double previous = 0;
    double guess = x;

    while (simple_abs(guess - previous) > EPSILON)
    {
        previous = guess;
        guess = previous - (previous * previous - x) / (2 * previous);
    }

    return guess;
}
int lop(int status) {
    return (status >> 8) & 0xff;
}

int square(int n) {
printf("number = %d  and square = %d", n , n*n);
    return n * n;
}

int root(int n) {
    return (int) simple_sqrt((double) n);
}

int doubleVal(int n) {
    return n * 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    int result = value;
    if (argc > 2){
    result = doubleVal(result);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            if (*argv[i] == 's' && *(argv[i]+1) == 'q' && *(argv[i]+2) == 'u' && *(argv[i]+3) == 'a' && *(argv[i]+4) == 'r' && *(argv[i]+5) == 'e' && *(argv[i]+6) == '\0'){
                result = square(result);
            } else if (argv[i][0] == 'r' && argv[i][1] == 'o' && argv[i][2] == 'o' && argv[i][3] == 't' && argv[i][4] == '\0')  {
                result = root(result);
            } else if (argv[i][0] == 'd' && argv[i][1] == 'o' && argv[i][2] == 'u' && argv[i][3] == 'b' && argv[i][4] == 'l' && argv[i][5] == 'e' && argv[i][6] == '\0') {
                result = doubleVal(result);
            } else {
                printf("Unknown operation: %s\n", argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
            exit(result);
        } else {
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            result = (status >> 8) & 0xff;
        }
    }
    }
    else {
    result = doubleVal(result);
    }

    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: lop function is same as of WEXITSTATUS but i just manually implemented here.

Comment: OT: `man strcmp()`... a very useful function....

Comment: @Fe2O3 It is constraint to use only limited functions in which strcmp is not included that is why i implemented lop instead of using WEXITSTATUS

Comment: "_only limited functions_" Apart from being a silly constraint, you _could_ write your own (trivial) version of `my_strcmp()` and clean up **your** code so that it is legible... The indentation is wonky, too, making the whole thing _non-obvious_...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I know you are right clean code matters but now i just want to spot the error can you do it

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse... Take your foot off the accelerator to "slow down and clean up and consolidate" what you've written so far... Perhaps you will diagnose your problem yourself. This is why one does these kind of exercises.

Comment: Please clean up this mess and write and use your own strcpmp function.

Comment: btw: if the square of 2 is 4, then the square of 8 is 64, not 256. What version of what code are you reporting the results from? Just an example of being so focussed on "arriving" that one is blind to the mistakes one makes during the passage...

Comment: @Fe2O3 please see my new updated question as i found what was problem [updated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371432/how-to-share-the-pass-the-value-from-child-to-parent-in-this-inifinte-unary-oper)

Comment: I don't understand why you want me to look at the updated version. I glanced at it and see that you've ignored my advice to clean up the code to make it readable. Good luck to you.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I apologize i am very very busy sir at the moment so i did,nt change that right now but i am assure that is not problem where you have to look at.

Comment: What you don't seem to see is that you've slashed your way forward trying to get something done and it's not working. The "updated" question indicates that the "str*" functions (like `strcmp()`) are usable in this assignment. So, having squandered your time with a copy/paste hack that is unreadable trying to get 4 functions working, the inter-process challenge has been left to a time when you are "very very busy". There's "experience" for you. Learn from it. (The prof would likely give you 70% if one function worked for values > 255.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 I undertood what you are try to say about strcmp() and i know you are right but other emotional things i am not understanding maybe be because of my lack of english skills. If you don,t want to help just because of that strcmp() function there is no problem. I am attending my lab so my teacher is infront of me that,s why i am busy.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that the data that can be passed from child to parent is limited. I'm giving away too much by suggesting that you reverse the flow of compounding results. Let the parent perform the first operation (right to left) `argv[argc-2]`, store the result, then fork a child process to perform the next operation, etc... The last child performs the argv[1] operation and outputs its result. All parents wait for their children to terminate before exiting. Recursion using the OS process stack... (And fix the `strcmp()`... It's still an abomination.)

Answer (score 1):

You double the result before the loop.  That ain't right.  Added a newline to the `square()` output, and used `strcmp()` as original code was making my eyes hurt.

```
#include <string.h>

int square(int n) {
    printf("number = %d  and square = %d\n", n , n*n);
    return n * n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    int result = value;
    if (argc > 2){
        for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
            if(fork()) {
                int status;
                wait(&status);
                result = (status >> 8) & 0xff;
            } else {
                if(!strcmp(argv[i], "square"))
                    result = square(result);
                else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "root"))
                    result = root(result);
                else if(!strcmp(argv[i], "double"))
                    result = doubleVal(result);
                else {
                    printf("Unknown operation: %s\n", argv[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                exit(result);
            }
        }
    } else
        result = doubleVal(result);

    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return result; // 0 for success but I digress
}
```

Consider using `atol()` as you cannot detect errors in input with `atoi()`.  Currently if there are no command line arguments you end up doing atoi(*argv) which probably evaluates to 0 unless your program starts with a number.  Maybe explicitly check if `argv > 1`?

Sample session:

```
$ ./a.out double square root 2
number = 4  and square = 16
Result: 4
```

Per [exit(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), you cannot return a status greater than 0xFF (255):

> The  exit() function causes normal process termination and the least significant byte of status (i.e., status & 0xFF) is returned to the parent

Comment: please visit my updated question which provides the information about logical errors that exit just return return at 0-255 range and it gives wrong result if result is exceeded to 255 [updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371432/how-to-share-the-pass-the-value-from-child-to-parent-in-this-inifinte-unary-oper)

Comment: that does not solves the problem the output is still wrong for result which exeeds from 255

Comment: You do know that the process status is limited to 255, right?

Comment: I got to know after posting this question so i posted another question where i highlighted this problem [updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371432/how-to-share-the-pass-the-value-from-child-to-parent-in-this-inifinte-unary-oper)

Comment: @timpbill So what is the problem you are asking for help with in *this* question?  The two examples you gave don't match your code as you double the value so `square 2` should have returned 16, and the 2nd is example is matches your code.  The answer I gave removes the doubling so it now returns the values that I expect.  You cannot return values > 256 via the status.  So what is left in this question?

Comment: There is nothing left in this question brother i know that,s why new question is posted. The purpose of this question was to identify the problem. The problem was of i cannot return value greater than 255 via status but i figured out this problem without any help from this posted question . you may post answer of this question as i said answer is i cannot return value greater than 255 via status and i will accept that your answer.

Comment: I added that tidbit.