# How to share the pass the value from child to parent in this inifinte unary operations

Tags: c, process, fork, exec

I am try to implement a program to do this type of calculation in which i have to use only some limited system calls

- fork
- exec* family
- str* family
- ato* family
- printf, sprintf
- round
  The program name is double.c and the calculation looks like

```
./double square 3
output:36 as square(double(3))
```

I am using exit(result) to returning the result but as the range it is capable of is 0-255 but when the number exeeds from 255 it gives wrong result I have to impement this program just using these system api calls so i think pipe and munmap cannnot be used but how i can return bigger values than using just these functions

**What i tried is**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define EPSILON 0.001
double simple_abs(double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x : -x;
}

double simple_sqrt(double x)
{
    double previous = 0;
    double guess = x;

    while (simple_abs(guess - previous) > EPSILON)
    {
        previous = guess;
        guess = previous - (previous * previous - x) / (2 * previous);
    }

    return guess;
}
int lop(int status) {
    return (status >> 8) & 0xff;
}

int square(int n) {
printf("number = %d  and square = %d\n", n , n*n);
    return n * n;
}

int root(int n) {
    return (int) simple_sqrt((double) n);
}

int doubleVal(int n) {
    return n * 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);
int result = value;
    if (argc > 2){
    result = doubleVal(result);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            if (*argv[i] == 's' && *(argv[i]+1) == 'q' && *(argv[i]+2) == 'u' && *(argv[i]+3) == 'a' && *(argv[i]+4) == 'r' && *(argv[i]+5) == 'e' && *(argv[i]+6) == '\0'){
                result = square(result);
            } else if (argv[i][0] == 'r' && argv[i][1] == 'o' && argv[i][2] == 'o' && argv[i][3] == 't' && argv[i][4] == '\0')  {
                result = root(result);
            } else if (argv[i][0] == 'd' && argv[i][1] == 'o' && argv[i][2] == 'u' && argv[i][3] == 'b' && argv[i][4] == 'l' && argv[i][5] == 'e' && argv[i][6] == '\0') {
                result = doubleVal(result);
            } else {
                printf("Unknown operation: %s\n", argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }

       printf("Child result: %d\n", result);
       //return result;
            exit(result);
        } else {
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            //result = (status >> 8) & 0xff;
        result = lop(status);#lop is working as WEXITSTATUS system api 
        }
    }
    }
    else {
    result = doubleVal(result);
    }

    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to do this to get correct result because when i try `./double square 8` it give wrong result as the result exceeds from 255 .

Comment: If your instructor is severely limiting what you can use, then they must have some specific technique in mind for inter-process communication.  Pipes are an obvious choice.  Using exit codes seems like a bad way to go, for many reasons (some of which you're already noticed).  I suggest bringing this up with your instructor, and asking what they had in mind.

Comment: i think pipe is good choice but is pipe comes in these listed system api calls? or is there any way to do this i know you are right exit code is bad .